# ERR_HTTP2_INADEQUATE_TRANSPORT_SECURITY on dotnet core 3.1 react project

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, dotnet-new

I started a new `dotnet` core with react project on my Windows 8.1 machine.

```
dotnet new react my-project
```

When I started debugging in chrome at `https://localhost:5001/`, I got the following error

```
ERR_HTTP2_INADEQUATE_TRANSPORT_SECURITY.
```

Where should I look into?

Comment: Please check if [this github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14350) describes the cause.

Answer (score 9):

You can configure Kestrel server to serve Http1. Please follow the following instruction to solve the problem -

1. Go to your project appsettings.json file.
2. Add below code under  "AllowedHosts": "*" line

   "Kestrel": {
   "EndpointDefaults": {
   "Protocols": "Http1"
   }
   }

Your default appsettings.json file will look like this -

```
{
   "Logging": {
      "LogLevel": {
         "Default": "Information",
         "Microsoft": "Warning",
         "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
   },
   "AllowedHosts": "*",
   "Kestrel": {
      "EndpointDefaults": {
         "Protocols": "Http1"
      }
   }
}
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: This solves problem for me. But i would like to understand for myself why this happens. Other team members do not have this issue. My OS is windows 10 pro.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/5.0/kestrel-disables-http2-over-tls